# Load the content of a template after pressing a button

Tags: angularjs

How can I can load a search results template only after the search button has been pressed?

Here is a sample of my code:

app.js

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('app', ['app-directives']);

  app.controller('AppController', function() {
    this.buttonClick = function() {
      alert('Test');
    };
  });
})();
```

directives.js

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('app-directives', []);

    app.directive('searchForm', function() {
       return {
         retrict: 'E',
         templateUrl: '/partials/search-form.html'
       };
    });

    app.directive('searchResults', function() {
       return {
         retrict: 'E',
         templateUrl: '/partials/search-results.html'
       };
    });
})();
```

search-form.html

```
<input type="text" id="query" />
<button onclick="buttonClick">Search</button>
```

page-content.html

```
<section id="mainContent">
    <search-form></search-form>
    <search-results></search-results>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to just show and hide a content, why not try with [ng-show or ng-hide](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_htmldom.asp)?

Example

```
<search-results ng-show="buttonPressed"></search-results>
OR
<search-results ng-hide="buttonNotPressed"></search-results>
```

Unless by 'load' you mean getting the template from a file?

Comment: I mean load from a file

Comment: Oh, so you mean to say for example, your results page has a large file size, and you would like to request the file only after the button is pressed?

Comment: I've been searching around the web as well, but to no avail yet. Will update answer as soon as I find it.
Btw, may I ask why do you need the html page to be loaded on demand?